# Как получить выбранное значение в выпадающем списке с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Я попробовал многие способы, но все они возвращают индекс выбранного элемента, а не значение:

```
var as = document.form1.ddlViewBy.value;
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

// Это одна из простейших форм, написанная Narendra Kottamidde:

var value = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
```

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/)» [@Danferd Lan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127986/danferd-lan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть выбранный элемент, который выглядит следующим образом:

```html
<select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

То выполнив следующий код:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Переменной `strUser` будет присвоено значение `2`. Если, на самом деле, вы хотите получить `test2` в `strUser`, вам надо выполнить следующее:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

И тогда переменной `strUser` будет присвоено значение `test2`.

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/564240)» [@Paolo Bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col s6 centered" id="CountrySelect"><select class="browser-default" id="countrySelect" name="Id">
        <option disabled="disabled">Select language</option>
        <option value="be">1. be - Belarusian(Беларуская)</option>
        <option value="de">2. de - German(Deutsch)</option>
        <option value="en">3. en - English(English)</option>
        <option value="fr">4. fr - French(français)</option>
        <option value="it">5. it - Italian(italiano)</option>
        <option value="pl">6. pl - Polish(polski)</option>
        <option value="ru-RU">7. ru-RU - Russian (Russia)(русский (Россия))</option>
    </select>
</div>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const EL = document.getElementById("CountrySelect");
    if (!!EL) {
        EL.addEventListener("change", e => {
            const lang = e.target.value;
            console.log(lang);
        });
    }
});
```

У меня есть выпадающий список `name="Id"`, есть опции, например, `value="pl"`. Я вешаю событие в момент когда `DOM` загружен (подробнее в `DOMContentLoaded`). Событие вешаю на элемент с `DIV`, в котором список, событие `change`. `e.target` — это элемент, на который вы изменили, а `e.target.value` - это собственно значение `pl`. И я вывожу его в консоль, могу делать что угодно `console.log(lang);`.

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить код в ответе, пожалуйста?

Comment: ? у меня есть выпадающий список name="Id", есть опции например value="pl". Я вешаю событие в момент когда DOM загружен (подробнее в 'DOMContentLoaded'), Событие вешаю на элемент с DIV в котором список, событие "change". e.target это элемент на который вы изменили, а e.target.value - это собственно значение "pl". И я вывожу его в консоль, могу делать что угодно console.log(lang);

Comment: Подскажите, это вопрос или ответ?

Comment: ответ, уточните что именно Вы не понимаете в коде?

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Это скорее вопрос к тому, что когда наши коллеги попадут на вопрос из поиска, было бы здорово если бы в вашем ответе были пояснения, прочитав которые можно было усвоить информацию лучше.